# Model Probability Calibration in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, calibration, imbalanced-data

I am using PySpark to implement a Churn classification model for a business problem and the dataset I have is imbalanced. So when I train the model, I randomly select a dataset with equal numbers of 1's and 0's.
Then I applied the model in a real-time data and the number of predicted 1's and 0's were obviously equal.

Now, I need to calibrate my trained model. But I couldn't find a way to do it in PySpark. Does anyone have an idea how to calibrate a model in PySpark, May be something like CalibratedClassifierCV ?

Comment: Hey, this is an old question, but you can basically do the calibration "by-hand". Platt scaling is the most common calibration method and it consists in fitting a new Logistic Regression model where X = model scores and y = real target